# How to set value of " this.props.history.location.pathname " manually without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on small extension to add my map based project. That extension should show lat, long of place on URL [like this](http://mlevans.com/leaflet-hash/map.html#12/37.7630/-122.4437)! Whenever location changes by user.

Problem is I could not change pathname of this.props.history.location when user changes location for second time

```
this.map.on("moveend", e => {
      if (!this.props.history.location.pathname.substr(4)) {
        console.log(this.props.history.location, "no change");
        this.props.history.replace(
          [
            "map",
            e.target._zoom,
            e.target._lastCenter.lat,
            e.target._lastCenter.lng
          ].join("/")
        );
      } else {
        console.log(this.props.history.location, "change");
      }
    });
```

Comment: this.props.history.push('/yourRoute/param1/param2');

Comment: push method is adding new path to prev path. my present url /map/param1/param2/ afer push /map/param1/map/param3/param4

Answer (score 1):

First of All keep URL in some constant:

```
const URL = http://mlevans.com/leaflet-hash/map.html#12/lat/long
```

whenever location changes you get `lat` and `long` then do stuff like:

```
const mapURL = URL.replace(lat, long, this.history.match.params.lat , this.history.match.params.long);
this.history.push(mapURL);
```

In react router you should have component mapped to `http://mlevans.com/leaflet-hash/map.html#12/:lat/:long`